# How to disable services when Ubuntu loads?

Tags: services

I need to disable docker services when Ubuntu 18.04 starts.  I tried with:

```
update-rc.d -f <service> remove
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: Which service in particular? In general, services in Ubuntu 18.04 are disabled via `systemctl disable $servicename`.

Comment: Hi PerlDuck, i'm trying disabled docker services.

Comment: Thanks PerlDuck, i solved my problem with your command, but i remember used this command previoulsy and don't work :) Now worked fine!

Comment: Nice to hear that. You are welcome. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The command to disable services on rebooting of Ubuntu based systems

```
 systemctl disable servicename
```

---

<sub>for centos6: `chkconfig servicename off`</sub>